# VSCode: settings.json file is not recognizing a terminal.integrated setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

Why is this entry not recognized by VSCode? I have a very slow terminal output that I am hoping this will help fix:

`"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "experimentalWebgl"`

The above command is known to exist, here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/master/docs/editor/integrated-terminal.md

Here is my settings.json file:

```
{
    "atomKeymap.promptV3Features": true,
    "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
    "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Anaconda3",
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Visual Studio Dark",
   "terminal.integrated.rendererType": "experimentalWebgl",  # grey'd out assuming its not a real command
    "workbench.iconTheme": "Monokai Pro Icons",
    "workbench.editorAssociations": {
        "*.ipynb": "jupyter-notebook"
    },
    "python.defaultInterpreterPath": "C:\\Users\\Andrew\\Anaconda3",
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
    "notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
        "default": "right",
        "jupyter-notebook": "left"
    },
    "debug.javascript.pickAndAttachOptions": {
    
    },
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The referenced markdown documentation file is not up to date (note that it's on branch `master`, while current development happens on the `main` branch). The [WebGL renderer has been made the default in v1.55 (March 2021)](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_55#_webgl-renderer-is-the-new-default):

> As part of this work we also added some fallback logic. When `"terminal.integrated.rendererType": "auto"`, the following happens:
>
> 1. The WebGL renderer will try to start up.
> 2. If it fails, for example due to lack of OS/browser support:
>
>    - The canvas renderer will be enabled and the time it takes to render a frame will start to be measured.
> 3. If the first 20 frames are rendering slowly, for example if there are hardware issues or GPU rendering is disabled:
>
>    - The DOM renderer will be enabled.
>
> In the next release, we plan on removing the `rendererType` setting all together in favor of a much more understandable `"terminal.integrated.gpuAcceleration": "auto" | "on" | "off"`.

See the [current documentation on this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_im-having-problems-with-the-terminal-rendering-what-can-i-do) for further reference.